# How are Logical-Operators operated among three boolean variates?

Tags: php, boolean, logical-operators

I'm a beginner in PHP now and not versed with program logic, so this epic of codes really confused me.

The final results that are returned to me are "true false". In my mind the result should be both false because "$b" and "$c" have different values so they can't satisfy the condition "and".

Also, if it's "$a" and "$b" be operated firstly as a group, the result of "$a or $b" should be "true" and that doesn't equal $c either.

Thanks a lot!

The version is PHP7

```
<?php
$a = true;
$b = true;
$c = false;

if($a or $b and $c)
echo 'true'." ";
else 
echo 'false';
?>
```

result page:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSRaJ.png)

Comment: If you want to check that two variables have the same value you need to use `==` (or `===` for same type as well) `and` is just saying they both have a non false value.

Comment: I do not get true and false at the same time. https://3v4l.org/aTEOK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in doubt use parenthesis to make the conditions explicit. That way it is easier to understand the code later on.

The order of the conditions depends on the operator priority, if it is the same it is left to right.

However PHP actually optimizes the conditions while processing them. In case of `$c1 or $c2`, if `$c1` is `true`, the value of `$c2` does not matter so it is not validated. The result can only be `true`. The same happens for `$c1 and $c2` - if `$c1` is false, the result of the overall condition can only be `false`.

So `($a or $b and $c)` is the same as `($a or ($b and $c))` for your expected result use `(($a or $b) and $c)`.

Here is a small script that allows you to test it out:

```
// a small function with some debug output
function createConditions(bool ...$values) {
    return function($callIndex) use ($values) {
        echo 'Call #', $callIndex, "\n";
        return $values[$callIndex - 1] ?? false;
    };
}
$c = createConditions(true, true, false);

if ($c(1) or $c(2) and $c(3)) {
    echo "Result: TRUE\n\n";
} else {
    echo "Result: FALSE\n\n";
}

if (($c(1) or $c(2)) and $c(3)) {
    echo "Result: TRUE\n\n";
} else {
    echo "Result: FALSE\n\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Call #1 
Result: TRUE 

Call #1 
Call #3 
Result: FALSE
```